# Whats a good API for generating reports for a java web application?

Tags: java, reporting

I have a J2EE application that has a lot of reports, the situation now is the following:

Report filters' values are sent to the application over DWR mainly, the data are retrieved from Oracle DB throw DB procedures and returned back to the client.

However, some customization is required every now and then (new data filters, columns, ordering, ...), and these changes are painful to implement since we need to modify the JSPs, DB Procedures, the application itself, ...

What API do you recommend to use for such reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/project/project_home.php?group_id=102) is popular as I heard.
[ILog JViews](http://www.ilog.com/products/jviews/features.cfm) if you want to take the commercial route.

Comment: We haven't found any decent reporting API that covers our needs, however, another team in the company has already developed an engine for creating JasperReports in which the filters, ordering, SQL statements are configurable and easier to change, we only extended it for our needs.

So, JasperReports was a part of our solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) which is free and template based (though you need to pay for unlimited scalability options).  To change layouts, fonts etc and such you can do it in the doc or odf template.  Docmosis can spit out doc/pdf/odf/html etc from a Java server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough clout to recommend a major change, I would recommend going with an actual reporting service. Then DB guys can generate reports. They can whip reports up *much* more quickly than creating a whole new application for each report.

Comment: The issue with having the DB Guys generate reports is that DB Admins are not generally good at UI development.  An ideal solution is to abstract the data into a middle layer using stored procs or something like Information Object (bolt-on to BIRT).  Then the DB folks control the data and report designers/business analysts can do what they do best which is generate content.

I think the failures of reporting initiatives till now have been that there has been a desire to have one group "own" the process.  The fact is it is a two (or more) faceted process requiring data AND UI sensitivities.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [jExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) to produce Excel reports.

The [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) is more extensive Reporting engine from Eclipse foundation.